# How to use a string input as an array? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, return, operator-keyword

I'm trying to take the result of one array as a string, and use this result as the name of an already existing array.

```
var Jeep_Model: [String] = ["CJ",
                        "DJ",
                        "SJ",
                        "XJ",
                        "Comanche",
                        "YJ",
                        "TJ",
                        "JK"
                        //"Grand Cherokee",
                        //"Renegade",
                        //"Compass",
                        //"Commander",
                        //"Liberty",
                        //"Patriot",
                        //"Wagoneer"
                        ]

var CJ: [String] = ["CJ-1",
                "CJ-2",
                "CJ-2A",
                "CJ-V35",
                "CJ-4",
                "CJ-4M",
                "CJ-4MA",
                "CJ-3B",
                "CJ-5: Tuxedo Park Mark III",
                "CJ-5: Camper",
                "CJ-5: 462",
                "CJ-5: Renegade I",
                "CJ-5: Renegade II",
                "CJ-5: Super Jeep",
                "CJ-5: Golden Eagle",
                "CJ-5: Golden Eagle California Edition",
                "CJ-5: Golden Hawk",
                "CJ-5: Silver Anniversary",
                "CJ-6",
                "CJ-3B Long",
                "CJ-5A",
                "CJ-6A",
                "CJ-7",
                "CJ-5",
                "CJ-8: Scrambler",
                "CJ-10"
                ]
```

So if Jeep_Model returns CJ, then I want to be able to call CJ as an array. Does this question make sense and if so, is this even possible?

Jeep_Model returns "CJ", then I want to read the array CJ.count or CJ[2] etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names are evaluated at compile time you can't treat the name as a string value at runtime.

You need a dictionary, the key is the model returned from `Jeep_Model`, the value is the associated array.

The objects are shortened a bit

```
let Jeep_Model = ["CJ", "DJ", "SJ"]

let allModels  = ["CJ" : ["CJ-1", "CJ-2", "CJ-2A"], "DJ" : ["DJ... "], "SJ" : ["SJ... "]]
```

Now if `Jeep_Model` returns `CJ` you get the third CJ model with

```
let model = allModels["CJ"]![2] // -> "CJ-2A"
```